Error: dbt configuration is invalid : Parsing Error Env var required but not provided:
I have been facing this issue in dbt core while using the DBT Power user extension in VSCode.
Is there any way to tackle this error? I have set the environmental variable through the command prompt. Still, it is showing this error.DBT Power User Env Vars Error
I have tried multiple ways to pass the environmental variables. but it didn't work.

The yml file is not valid : https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/model-configs

Please post error output as text, rather than screen-dumps. That way, it is more easily searched. Given that the error is reported against the YML file, could you post that file in the question too? Code and error-output should be delimited by triple-back-ticks.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
